# How to set application identity of an application pool using web administration module in powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity, web-administration

I am using powershell to automate configuring websites in my IIS.
I have the following code that creates a web application pool for me

```
#Creating a new Application Pool
New-WebAppPool "NewAppPool"
```

**How do I go about setting the application pool identity to "Network Service" from my script ?**

**Please note : There is no IIS Drive on my system.** And hence commands which have IIS mentioned in the path like the following fail :

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\NewAppPool -name processModel.identityType -value 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import the **WebAdministration** module, **PowerShell** builds a drive called **IIS**. This drive allows you to manage *IIS* just like you would via the file system by simply using *IIS:* instead of *C:* to represent the drive.

You can create a Pool like:

```
    New-Item IIS:\AppPools\$AppPool
    $NewPool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$AppPool
    $NewPool.ProcessModel.Username = "$Username"
    $NewPool.ProcessModel.Password = "$Password"
    $NewPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = 2
    $NewPool | Set-Item
```

So for using the below command you have to use the WebAdministration module:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\NewAppPool -name processModel.identityType -value 2
```

Hope it helps.