# How to check whether an application pool exists or not in IIS using powershell and web administration module?

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, web-administration

I am using powershell to automate configuring websites in my IIS. I have the following code that creates a web application pool for me

```
#Creating a new Application Pool
New-WebAppPool "NewAppPool"
```

But before creating the pool, **I want to check whether pool exists or not.How do I go about doing this?**

**Please note : There is no IIS Drive on my system.** And hence commands which have IIS mentioned in the path like the following **fail** :

```
$IISPath = "IIS:\AppPools"
cd $IISPath
if (Test-Path ".\NewAppPool") { Write-Host "NewAppPool exists." }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this:

```
import-module webadministration

$AppPoolName="NewAppPool"

if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$AppPoolName)
{
"AppPool is already there"
return $true;
}
else
{
"AppPool is not present"
"Creating new AppPool"
New-WebAppPool "$AppPoolName" -Force
return $false;
}
```

Note: You need the WebAdministration module for Powershell. After importing you can use it. See the other [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246712/how-to-set-application-identity-of-an-application-pool-using-web-administration) where I have mentioned about IIS drive

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: Good to help you.

Comment: In some cases this would return false for an existing application pool.  i had to add import-module webadministration to the top of the file.

Comment: Minor suggestion, I would change the if statement like this:

Comment: @TonyT_32909023190: Like what ? I didnt get it.. Kindly edit your comments or post an answer.